# Why am I able to use the parameters passed to the class definition?

Tags: scala

I'm just learning about classes and objects and Scala, and yesterday I saw something like this:

```
class Foo(bar: Int) {
  def increaseByOne = bar + 1
}
```

Why am I able to use `bar` in method `increaseByOne`? I would expect the the method definition complain about not knowing `bar`.

I though the right way to define such a class would be

```
class Foo(x: Int) {
  val bar = x

  def increaseByOne = bar + 1
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's one of the wonderful features of Scala: if you reference constructor argument from any method that is not a constructor, Scala will automatically assign that constructor variable to a field. So effectively Scala translates your first code snippet into the second one for you (with `private[this]` modifier).

Moreover, preceding constructor argument with `val`/`var` will create getters/setters as well:

```
class Foo(val bar: Int)
val foo = new Foo(42);
println(foo.bar)
```

Comment: +1 For explaining what putting val/var in front of the parameters. Pretty nice feature :-).

Answer (score 2):

In this case `bar` is defined as `private[this]` and can be acessed within the class definition. You can check it with `-Xprint:typer` option:

```
class Foo extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val bar: Int = _;
  def this(bar: Int): $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.Foo = {
    Foo.super.this();
    ()
  }
}
```